# How this inequality works to know a point cross a line or not?

Tags: intersection-theory

First of all, sorry for my bad english..
but i really want to know how this works.

[image: The coords and formula]

as you see in the picture, there are 3 points and 
if leftside is greater than rightside,
It means the point p0 is not cross the line(p1 - p2).

I can't understand and where it come from?

I think it is something with gradient(slope).. but don't know why. anyone can help me?

thanks!

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by "a point cross a line".

Comment: Looking at your formula, it seems to determine which side of the line through $P_1$ and $P_2$ the point $P_0$ lies on.

Comment: Thank you Tony K. Yes you're right. It determine what you said... but i can't understand how that formula works for it..?

Comment: TonyK, thanks to your comment, i can search and find a answer for this! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560492/how-to-tell-whether-a-point-is-to-the-right-or-left-side-of-a-line